# How to I properly link and enable Typeahead for Bootstrap 3 using an external file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I've got [this example](http://www.bootply.com/V9izsIM0QX#) and it works as supposed to under the condition that the loooooong line with JavaScript is uncommented. (I'm guessing it's the script for Typeahead.)

```
!function(a){...}
$('#query').typeahead({ local: ['alpha','bravo','charlie'] });

<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" name="query" id="query" type="text">              
</div>
```

Of course, I don't want that line to be there. Instead, I've tried to link it externally (by the commented-out line in the HTML) and also by making it a part of a bundle.

The question is how to make the type-ahead work in that example without the need to explicitly shove in all the contents of the script file into my code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that bootply might not be a great place for working with external libraries.  I'm not sure as I've only used it for Bootstrap specific things.

[I explicitly added a link to jQuery](http://www.bootply.com/iTX7vK3BFo#) and that stops the errors related to jQuery, but that doesn't fix your implementation of the typeahead.  If you examine the browser dev tools when you attempt to run, you will see the errors related to JavaScript.  I'm think the bootply in question was referencing a version of JavaScript not supported by Typeahead.js.

You were also using version 0.9.3 (several versions ago), which I've never used and the is not referenced in the current documentation.  As such, I am including some information on using it with the current release (1.11).

[Here is an example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/b7ory8mh/) that should be basically the same as your example.

There were several things that needed to change:

The basic declaration for typeahead is `jQuery#typeahead(options, [*datasets])', with`datasets` being optional.  The example I use is to declare a typeahead with both an options hash and a dataset definition:

```
$('#query').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
}, {
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(vals)
});
```

The only reference to `local` with typeahead is when using `bloodhound`.

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/umc5bjy8/) using bloodhound and a local data source.

The difference is that you declare the bloodhound instance:

```
var states = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
  local: globalResults
});
```

And then give that instance to the typeahead:

```
$('#search-input').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
}, {
  name: 'myMatches',
  source: states
});
```

Here are [the docs for typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) that might give you a bit more insight.